# A general question regarding images to be used in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, appstore-approval

This is my first iPhone application. So I have this long list of doubts :-)

My application has a `UItableView` on the first tab and a Contact us page on the third tab. In both these tabs I display images.

For the `UITableView` i get images from the server and for the contact us page I have a set of static images of my client.

My question is, is there any specifications on the quality of these images that I should follow to get my App approved in Appstore?? These images are readable, but not of high resolution.

I know there are guidelines on the Tabbar icon images, the splash screen images. But what about the static images and the images i receive from the server?

Guidance or help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel the image is good then use it.. Apple wont gonna reject your app due to images.
But just keep in mind that there are few icons defined by apple for specific purpose like action icon for opening actionsheet, camera icon for opening camera console or wallpaper.

Just keep in mind that you are not changing the behaviour of the predefined icons....
Rest all is fine..

Happy iCoding...

Comment: One additional question. Till now i get 40*40 image from the server to display on the TableView. should i ask for 80*80 to make it look better in iPhone 4. ?

Comment: It would be great if u ask for double for retina display as it shows double points in 1 pixel for better clearity..

Comment: can you please guide me on how to find out if its iphone 4?

Comment: Its not required.. jus keep the extension of @2x after teh name of every image.. if its iPhone4 it will search for the imagename with @2x extension.. and if it dont find it then it will take the image with normal image. Eg: for normal if u r using "1.png" then the image with double pixel must be name "1@2x.png".. Thats it :)

Comment: as I told earlier, for the tablveview i get the images as a string. I access the url to get the image. In that case, if the user uses iPhone4 i will call for the corresponding 2x image

Comment: you can check out the resolution of the screen.. for regular iPhone its 320x480 and for iPhone 4 its exactly double.. you can use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`

Comment: also regarding the thanks I must say.. Getting a vote is the best way to thanks :P

Answer (score 2):

There are specifications based on display. However it is not mandatory to support both the displays (normal and retina).

You may want to dig more into the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html). If you don't have images of double resolution then on the retina display the appearance of the app may be bad.

However you can use any image(barring other violation like DRM, copyrights etc) in your app.
Approval is also based on a large number of parameters. The images may not be a part of it.However they will specify it explicitly if rejected.

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean its advisable to fix 2x images for all the images that I am using in my App? (I don think my client even has 2x images for everything)

Comment: Nope, you may or may not want the 2x images. It all depends on how serious you are about the images part of the app. If images dont play a major role and it mostly on content and text, then you may drop making 2x images. It increases the binary size.